# How to do state tomography when using sampling in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

Could anyone please explain how do I do state tomography when using sampling (on real device or QASM) in Qiskit? I know there's a [special method for this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.ignis.verification.state_tomography_circuits.html), but I could not find a working example.

More precisely, I would be interested in two cases: when the full state tomography is performed (all the $2^n$ amplitudes are measured) and when it's known apriori that the wave function has support in a certain subspace (say, only $|10\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$ for a two-qubit system).

BTW, is $3^n$ a lower bound on the number of operators which have to be measured in order to perform the state tomography? ($X$, $Y$, $Z$ for each qubit.)

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now on the entire question, but at least there used to be a wonderful qiskit tutorial notebook on QST (although I can't find it anymore). I'll try to answer later if there is no answer yet.

Comment: The $3^{n}$ bound is not a strict bound; in principle you could do with $4^{n}$ state populations (the $3^{n}$ operators of course give $6^{n}$ states) when you use a SIC-POVM - but in practice, it's just easier to use the $3^{n}$ Pauli operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use the code from  the tutorial about quantum state tomography, adapting it to a real device of your choice. You can find the updated tutorial [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/344cf552e190a4f68bee3643b0b563236b2919b0/qiskit/ignis/state_tomography.ipynb)

Caveat: as state tomography requires 3^n circuits, you will need probably to find a method of batch processing of these circuits if they exceed the job circuit limit of your real device. See the code [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/ignis/verification/tomography/basis/circuits.html)

“This performs measurement in the Pauli-basis resulting in :math:`3^n circuits for an n-qubit state tomography experiment.”

For an example of results of « full state tomography » on real devices (Melbourne and ibmqx4) for up to 5 qubits, I suggest you have a look at the end of my own qiskit tutorial [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/344cf552e190a4f68bee3643b0b563236b2919b0/community/terra/qis_adv/Multi-Qubit_W_States_with_Tomography.ipynb)

For the exploration of a certain subspace on a real device, I have some doubt about the approach as noise will inevitability produce a result somewhere in the entire Hilbert space and not confined to the chosen subspace.

However, you may be interested by [this recent paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-020-0932-7)

and by its [presentation in Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2020-07-method-properties-complex-quantum.html)

I quote from this presentation written by Ingrid Fadelli

“By combining statistical learning and unitary t-design theory, the researchers were able to devise a rigorous and efficient procedure that allows classical machines to produce approximate classical descriptions of quantum many-body systems. These descriptions can be used to predict several properties of the quantum systems that are being studied by performing a minimal number of quantum measurements.”

So, you are surely right in proposing that full tomography can be replaced by alternate methods using a lower number of measurements.

For your last question about the 3^n bound, I see that JSdJ already answered to you.

Comment: just fyi, you can add links typing e.g. `[click here](http://www.google.com)`, which gives you [click here](http://www.google.com)

Comment: As a small sidenote, there is another reason why only considering a subspace during reconstruction is tricky, as not (ac)counting for projections on other subspaces as valid measurement outcomes results in essentially 'lost' measurements (i.e. you performed a measurement but did not record the outcome). Reconstructing for $\rho$ will then not only disregard the information regarding these subspaces, but will also not be trace-class, meaning that the trace of the state will not be $1$.

Comment: @gIS thanks for your remark. Accordingly I edited the text using mini-Markdown formatting.

Comment: @JSdJ Thank for your sidenote which expresses more precisely the concerns about only considering a subspace.